# How can I make the entire HTML document scroll when the mouse is hovering over a specific DIV?

Tags: html, css, mousewheel

My page contains two vertical DIVS: nav_div and content_div. My CSS looks like this:

```
#nav_div{ 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content_div{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 
    left: 300px;
    overflow: auto; 
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
}
```

What I want to accomplish:  make the entire page scroll vertically **WITH THE MOUSEWHEEL** if the mouse is hovering over nav_div

Comment: All browsers should support vertical scrolling with the mousewheel regardless of the content of the page.  Do you mean that you only want content_div to scroll, not nav_div?  Please clarify.

Comment: exactly...  i thought my CSS was showing that.  nav_div should NEVER scroll, while content_div should ALWAYS scroll...  with the mouse wheel of course, regardless of where the mouse pointer is

Answer (score 1):

This won't work with pure html/css. You need javascript to accomplish what you want. You can find a jQuery example here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please provide a jsfiddle or at least share some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `nav_div` to remain stationary, it is the one that should have `position:fixed`:

```
#nav_div{ 
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content_div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 300px;
    overflow: auto; 
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#nav_div{ 
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content_div{
    margin-left: 300px;
    overflow: auto; 
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
}
```